# Using .htaccess to redirect traffic to same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

Well it's kind of hard typing a title to describe what I want to do.

Basically I have a website that I've been asked to develop a mobile site for. This website has various domains (such as `.co.za`,`.com`,`.za.net`) but they all run from the same folder on the server (so I only have one .htaccess file).

I want to be able to redirect the traffic that goes to `www.example.co.za` to `m.example.co.za` and traffic that goes to `www.example.com` to `m.example.com`.

How would I need to modify this .htaccess file to achieve that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.%2/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, just change the last line to: `RewriteRule ^$ http://m.%2/ [L,R=302]` and I'll upvote and accept. This answer pointed me in the right direction! :)